# Не запускается эмулятор (ARM) в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Появляется вот такая надпись и всё, больше ничего не происходит. 
Использую ARM, т.к. проц от AMD.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

1. Попробуйте включить в bios'е компа виртуализацию *VT-X/SVM*
2. Попробуйте *armeabi v.7*
3. Если ничего все равно не получается попробуйте [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com)